# proof : f continuous at a then |f| is continuous at a

Tags: limits, continuity, solution-verification, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

Here's my proof, which I am not sure is correct :

Assume f is continuous at a

$=> \lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$

$=> \lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists

$=> \lim \limits_{x \to a} |f(x)| = | \lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) | = | f(a) |$

Hence, |f| is continuous at a

Is there something wrong with it ?

Comment: Do you already know what the absolute value function is continuous? Do you know that the composition of continuous functions is continuous? If you do, then it's correct. If you don't, it is circular. In either case you should just prove it using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ to make it rock solid.

Comment: I do know that the composition of continuous functions is continuous. I guess I should say that x -> |x| is continuous, though.

I honestly didn't know the version of the triangle inequality mentioned in the answers and that is why I couldn't prove it using ε-δ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line $\lim | f(x) | = | \lim f(x) |$ is using the assumption of continuity of $|\cdot|$, so your argument does not work. The defining property of continuity is the statement that limits can be passed inside.

Instead, you can use the version of the triangle inequality: $$| |x| - |y| | \le |x-y|.$$

In particular, using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity:

Suppose $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\delta > 0$ be such that for any $|x-a| < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

Then this means that $||f(x)| - |f(a)|| < |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$ for all $|x-a| < \delta$. Hence $|f(x)|$ is continuous.

---

Since you might find it helpful here is a quick proof of $||x|-|y|| < |x-y|$:

$$|x| = |x-y+y| < |x-y| + |y|$$

This means $|x|-|y| < |x-y|$.

$$|y| = |y-x+x| < |y-x| + |x| = |x-y| + |x|$$

In turn this tells us that $|y|-|x| < |x-y|$ or $-|x-y| < |x|-|y|$.

Hence $$-|x-y| < |x|-|y| < |x-y|$$
and $| |x| - |y| | < |x-y|$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $||f(x)| - |f(a)|| \le |f(x) - f(a)|$